# How to dynamically decide and tell the d3.json() function which json to take when

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a d3 api in which i have to take two json files but i need to to tell the function that when it will take which one.Is it possible  ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply switch the URL to call:

```
var url = condition ? url1 : url2;
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
});
```

Comment: here url is Servlet write?

Comment: `url` is the URL that you call to get the JSON.

Comment: var servlet="LinkServlet";
                        var servlet1="AServlet";
                         
                        var url=(j>0)?servlet:servlet1;
                        var url="LinkServlet";
                        d3.json(url,function(error, directed) {
 i am doing this but the LinkServlet is not replacing ,i need it first i.e the time of loading but them i need AServlet

Comment: You're resetting the `url` variable immediately after setting it.

Comment: var servlet="LinkServlet";
                        var servlet1="AServlet";
                        var url;
                        var  j=0;
                        function increment(){
                           j=j+1;
                                 
                        }   
                           if(j!=0){
                                url=servlet; 
                            }else{
                                url=servlet1;
                            }
                         i am doing this to switch between servlets